# How to make sure elements land on full pixel boundaries in a StackLayout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a StackLayout holding some elements for a custom cell in a ListView. The problem I am running in to is that my images are not landing on full pixel boundaries. This is causing the straight lines in my graphics to become blurry as they are not landing on pixel boundaries. Is there a way for me to easily prevent this behavior, perhaps in a custom renderer?

```
    public InputEditCell()
    {
        image = new Image { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
        image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Image.ImageNameSelect"));
        image.BindingContext = _tempInputViewModel;
        var tappedImageGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(OnImageTapped),
            CommandParameter = image
        };
        image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tappedImageGesture);

        nameEntry = new Entry()
        {
            TextColor = Color.FromHex("E60006"),
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Entry)),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        nameEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "Name");
        nameEntry.BindingContext = _tempInputViewModel;

        var acceptImage = new Image
        {
            Source = ResourceHandler.GetAcceptImage(),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
        };
        var tappedAcceptGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(OnAcceptTapped),
            CommandParameter = acceptImage
        };
        acceptImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(tappedAcceptGesture);

        var cancelImage = new Image
        {
            Source = ResourceHandler.GetCancelImage(),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
        };
        var tappedCancelGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(OnCancelTapped),
            CommandParameter = cancelImage
        };
        cancelImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(tappedCancelGesture);

        var viewLayout = new StackLayout {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = { image, nameEntry, acceptImage, cancelImage },
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 10, 10 ,10)
        };

        View = viewLayout;
        View.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
        View.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer());
    }
```

Comment: did you try out with "aspectfit"  and "aspectfull " properties of image class?

Comment: @saketkumar I tried all the different aspect types and none helped. I think perhaps I could overload the method that calculates the layout and round each position manually. Though I probably will just use a RelativeLayout instead.

Comment: If u get it done ok , if not , get us a dummy project depicting this problem , we can surely find a workaround ! and yes , whenever i am dealing with images i always use relative layout with ,fixed width and height ! .
you have rightly spotted it